# Multi-Image picker Library Permission issue

Tags: android, permissions, expo

Using expo version 37..0.12

While trying to load multi-images there is a permission error reading the images

Following is the error

```
Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.CAMERA,Permissions.CAMERA_ROLL, Permissions.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
Error: [Unhandled promise rejection: Error: Failed to get permissions]
```

This happens in Android while using multi-image picker library: "expo-image-picker-multiple": "1.4.0"

Answer (score 0):

I assume you already used this permission in your manifest

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />`.

If yes its probably because you don't have runtime permissions in your project like this

```
val requestPermissionLauncher =
    registerForActivityResult(RequestPermission()
    ) { isGranted: Boolean ->
        if (isGranted) {
            // Permission is granted. Continue the action or workflow in your
            // app.
        } else {
            // Explain to the user that the feature is unavailable because the
            // features requires a permission that the user has denied. At the
            // same time, respect the user's decision. Don't link to system
            // settings in an effort to convince the user to change their
            // decision.
        }
    }
```

[Ref: Android Docs for Runtime Permission](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting)